# Why is this COM code leaking?

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl, windows-shell

I'm maintaining an application which uses Windows Explorer overlay icons.  Occasionally some operations require me to forcibly refresh explorers view for a particular folder.  I do so using the following function which uses COM:

```
void RefreshExplorerView(CString strPath)
{
    CComPtr<IShellWindows> pShellWindows;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    if(SUCCEEDED(pShellWindows.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows)))
    {
        IDispatch* pFolder=NULL;
        VARIANT variant;
        V_VT(&variant) = VT_I4;

        for(V_I4(&variant) = 0; pShellWindows->Item(variant, &pFolder) == S_OK; V_I4(&variant)++)
        {
            CComPtr<IWebBrowserApp> pWebBrowserApp;
            if(SUCCEEDED(pFolder->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pWebBrowserApp))))
            {
                BSTR LocationURL = NULL;
                pWebBrowserApp->get_LocationURL(&LocationURL);

                if(LocationURL != NULL && strPath.CompareNoCase(LocationURL) == 0)
                {
                    CComPtr<IServiceProvider> pServiceProvider;
                    if(SUCCEEDED(pWebBrowserApp->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pServiceProvider))))
                    {
                        CComPtr<IShellBrowser> pShellBrowser;
                        if(SUCCEEDED(pServiceProvider->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellBrowser))))
                        {
                            IShellView* pShellView;
                            if(SUCCEEDED(pShellBrowser->QueryActiveShellView(&pShellView)))
                            {
                                pShellView->Refresh();
                                pShellView->Release();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                SysFreeString(LocationURL);
            }
            pFolder->Release();
            pFolder = NULL;
        }
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

I've noticed that when my program does this refresh regularly it slowly grows in size and UMDH has shown me that I appear to be leaking `pFolder` and `pShellWindow` instances every time this runs.  I can't work out why on earth this happens since as far as I can tell these are released properly.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You could replace IDispatch & IShellView by CComPtrs, BSTR by _bstr_t and VARIANT by _variant_t (comutil.h), this way, you will be sure nothing leaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You release `pShellWindows` after `CoUninitialize`, which is incorrect.

The rest of interfaces seem to be released fine. Note that you could improve cleanless and readability *greatly* by using `CComQIPtr` instead of `QueryInterface`, and not using raw pointers at all (`BSTR`, `IFoo*`) and replace them with smart auto-releasing wrappers.

`pFolder` might be leaking too, if `Item` call is successful but returns code other than `S_OK`. Again, use of `CComPtr<IFolder>` instead of `IFolder*` would immediately resolve this problem without even drawing any attention to it.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't spot the issue with pShellWindows ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
```

There's more than one problem with this statement.  @Roman explained how you can leak by uninitializing too soon.  But this will also go bad in more than one way, the apartment state of a thread is a Really Big Deal in COM:

- You are not checking the return value of CoInitialize().  This will blow up the client app that calls this function if it has already called CoInitializeEx() and selected MTA instead of STA.  That will make CoInitialize() fail, you cannot change the thread state after it was committed.  Your CoUninitialize() call will blow the client app to smithereens, making all of its subsequent COM calls fail.
- Selecting STA also requires that you implement the contract for a single threaded apartment.  Which states that you never block the thread, you're okay with that.  *And* that you pump a message loop.  The message loop is crucial to marshaling calls to the single-threaded apartment.  You are **not** okay with that, nor can you reasonably ensure that this is taken care of in a function like this.  Particularly important for the shell interfaces, the vast majority of them are not thread-safe.  The consequence of not pumping is deadlock.  You *may* get away with not pumping, it is not a guaranteed deadlock.  You'll get a bit of leeway here since these are probably out-of-process interfaces.

Particularly the last requirement can only be met by the code that created the thread that calls this function, only it is in control over what the thread does beyond calling your function.  If you cannot get the guarantee that the client app initializes COM correctly then the only truly safe thing to do is to create a thread yourself.

Comment: In this instance, the function is always called by a newly created thread which has been created to handle a pipe message which should mitigate your first point (although I will still check the return value).  Your second point does give me some concern though, can I mitigate this by simply using the multi-threaded model?

Comment: There's no free lunch in MTA, you'll leave it up to other code to take care of calling thread-unsafe code in a thread-safe way.  It is better to take that bull by the horns. I'm just telling you what might go wrong, you'll know what is wrong when you see the code deadlock.